# If a 3D-cake is cut by $n$ planes yielding the maximum number of pieces, then what is the number of pieces with the cake crust?

Tags: combinatorics

It is known that a 3D-cake can be cut by $n$ plane cuts at most into $N$ pieces, defined by [Cake Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number) $N=\frac {1}{6}(n^3+5n+6)$. However, some of the pieces would have a crust of the cake as one of their boundaries. How many pieces are with crust? (Entire surface of the cake is assumed to be crust).

Comment: @user14111 A camouflaged cheesecake?

Comment: Helpful: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/assignments/199S/cuttingplanes.pdf

Comment: @user14111: The kind of such a cake is Kolobok: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolobok

Comment: @user14111: Corrected the heading

Comment: It's not clear from the question where a cake's crust is. One of the answers seems to assume that the cake has one planar crust. The accepted answer and the comments under it seem to regard the entire surface of the cake as crust. The question should be clarified in this regard.

Comment: @joriki edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the maximum number, the cutting planes are in general position.

Consider the 2-D surface (crust) of the cake. Let the intersection of the cutting planes and the crust be denoted as cutting circles. Remove 1 point that is not on any of the cutting lines. Project what remains onto the plane. We now have $n$ circles in general position cutting the plane. We know that the [number of regions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlaneDivisionbyCircles.html) it divides it into is

$$n^2-n+2.$$

Comment: Consider a spherical cake is cut by two perpendicular planes. This produces four pieces of cake, all of them with crust. Two planes produce $n=2$ circles. Your formula gives number of crust-pieces equal to 2, but there are 4. Similarly, three planes give eight pieces, all of them with crust, but your formula gives 4.

Comment: @mbaitoff Indeed. I quoted the formula wrongly (see link). There is no denominator of 2.

Comment: I still don't understand. Consider we have 3 general circular divisions of the surface of the cake, having 8 pieces of crust. Next general cut would produce six new intersections with previous cuts on the cake surface, giving 14 pieces of crust. It corresponds to your formula, but how you project the cake surface on the plane? Riemann way? But would it transform cuts into circles? Or it is only important that the projections would be 'topological' circles?

Comment: @mbaitoff As you mentioned, the important consideration is the number of intersections. If you insist on knowing the map, remember that "Stereographic projection is circle preserving", hence everything that I said can be formalized.

Answer (score -1):

Number of pieces with crust $= ( n^2+n+2)/2$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! We expect answers to provide some insight into the problem under consideration, not just state the end result of reasoning. Please [edit] the post to add the argument that led to your formula. Also, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: This is the correct answer for a crust on one plane surface of the cake. It's not clear from the question, but it appears from the comments under the accepted answer that the OP regards the entire surface of the cake as crust. (I didn't downvote.)